# Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in Expense.php on line 10

Tags: php, oop

I found so many similar questions here, but i don't understand it because I am newbie in OOP.

I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLfdtiltiRHWF5Rhuk7k4UAU1_yLAZzhWc) tutorial series to learn OOP.

Here is my code:

```
include_once 'core/init.php';

if(Session::exists('home')){
    echo Session::flash('home');
}

$user = new User();
if($user->isLoggedIn()){
} else {
    Redirect::to('index.php');
}

if(Input::exist()){
    $validate = new Validate();
    $validation = $validate->check($_POST, array(
        'date' => array('required' => true),
        'vendor' => array('required' => true),
        'invoice-no' => array('required' => true),
        'terms-or-payment-account' => array('required' => true),
        'type-of-expense-1' => array('required' => true),
        'description-1' => array('required' => true),
        'quantity-1' => array('required' => true),
        'price-1' => array('required' => true),
        'amount-1' => array('required' => true)
    ));

    if($validation->passed()){
        $expense = new Expense();
        try{
            $expense->record(array(
                'date' => Input::get('date'),
                'vendor' => Input::get('vendor'),
                'invoice-no' => Input::get('invoice-no'),
                'terms-or-payment-account' => Input::get('terms-or-payment-account'),
                'type-of-expense' => Input::get('type-of-expense-1'),
                'description' => Input::get('description-1'), 
                'quantity' => Input::get('quantity-1'),
                'price' => Input::get('price-1'),
                'amount' => Input::get('amount-1')
            ));
        } catch(Exception $e){
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
        if($expense->record()){
            echo 'success';
        }
    } else {
         //output errors
        foreach ($validation->errors() as $error) {
            echo $error, '<br/>';
        }
    }
}
```

Expense.php:

```
class Expense{
    private $_db;

    public function __construct($expense = NULL){
        $this->_db = DB::getInstance();
    }

    public static function record($fields){
        if(!$this->_db->insert('expenses', $fields)){
            throw new Exception('There is a problem recording expense');
        }
    }
}
```

please help me to solve this issue. Thanks

Comment: We don't have line numbers in SO. Is `Redirect::to('index.php');` your line 10? If so, edit your question and put a comment in your line like `// here is line 10 - where it fails`.

Comment: it was if(!$this->_db->insert('expenses', $fields)){

and i have redirect class which you mentioned.

Comment: now my Expense class file is look like this.

class Expense{

 public function record($fields){
  if(DB::getInstance()->insert('expenses', $fields)){
   throw new Exception('There is a problem recording expense');
  }
 }}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Expense#record` function is static. This means that the object is not yet instantiated, but the class is. `$this` is a pointer to the instantiated object. Since there's no instantiated object in the scope of this method, `$this` will always return null. The error you see is PHP's way of telling you this.

The easiest way to make this work is to remove `static` from the `Expense#record` method signature. This would make the method a method of the Expense object instead of a method of the Expense class as it is right now. Since you're already instantiating an object of Expense after `$validation->passed()`, this should not be a problem. The `->record()` method would work as expected.

If you absolutely want to keep the record method as `static`, then you'd have to change the method to work in a static context; like below

```
class Expense{
    private static $_db = DB::getInstance();

    public static function record($fields){
        if(!self->_db->insert('expenses', $fields)){
            throw new Exception('There is a problem recording expense');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @YaskyThanks, Thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

Variable '**this**' is just link to object which called method. But you use static modificator. It is mean, this method use in whole class, not in some object. Also it is mean, what not exist object which call this method and evidently, not exist variable '**this**'.

At static method you can use variable '**self**' only. It link to self class.

And for solving your error, you need remove static modificator.

Comment: HI, Thank you for your answer. i just did duplicate User class.

Comment: you mean like this?
public static function record($fields){
  DB::getInstance()->insert('expenses', $fields)){
   throw new Exception('There is a problem recording expense');
  }
 }

Comment: when i changed to this 

public static function record($fields){
  DB::getInstance()->insert('expenses', $fields);
 }

record submitted,

Comment: Not exactly, but it possible too. If you will be use DB::getInstance(), then you can remove 'construct', because it is not necessary. And I did suggested remove 'static' modificator from method `public function record($fields)`. Because you get instance of db in constructor and other methods of this class can work with this connection.

Comment: Thank you for your answers.
<pre><code>
Warning: Missing argument 1 for Expense::record(), called in \expense.php on line 45 and defined in \Expense.php on line 4
NULL 
Warning: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in \DB.php on line 76

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in \DB.php on line 80

Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in \DB.php on line 88

Comment: Can't understand where errors. But it seems like lost params at Expense::record() and method return null.

Comment: var_dump($fields); is showing values. but not inserting in to db. showing those warnings. i just created login system as per the tutorial. i thought i can duplicate User class to Expense. but i don't understand how to solve. i will add my DB class to question. please check.

Comment: [class DB](http://pastebin.com/puGUxQKw) & [class User](http://pastebin.com/VLwks8Fj)

Comment: No, with DB and User all right. Error happens when you try call method `record` without params at line 45 in file expense.php, here `if($expense->record()){            echo 'success';}`

Comment: Thanks,  Thanks to all